# Is it possible to run a pygame application inside of a Tkinter application?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I have created a simulation in Pygame, but have recently found out about TkInter. I thought it would be cool to have buttons that start, pause, and quit my application as well as a score tracker while having my Pygame application wrapped around the GUI. The reason I am asking is because I don't want to rewrite my entire program (over 2000 lines of code) into TkInter.

I don't know if this is possible, but if it is, that would be absolutely amazing :)

**A picture for reference:**
[image: An image of Snake Game using python and tkinter]

Comment: `pygame` has some modules with `GUI` - see: [pygame.org - tag: GUI](https://www.pygame.org/tags/gui). Or create own buttons in `PyGame`

Comment: I don't remeber if tkinter and pygame have function to "embed" pygame in tkinter window. Other main problem is `mainloop` in tkinter and event loop in `pygame` - both loops has to run at the same time.